# serialize ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore crashes RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

As suggested in http://railscasts.com/episodes/345-hstore, I added:

```
serialize :properties, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
```

to my model. This allows me to iterate over key / value pairs in the view (without it, I get a undefined method `each' for String error):

```
<% @item.properties.try(:each) do |key, value| %>
  <%= key %>: <%= value %><br />
<% end %>
```

I managed to get the hstore field in RailsAdmin working by explicitly declaring it as a text field:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :properties, as: :admin

  serialize :properties, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore  

  rails_admin do # without this block, properties gets ignored in RailsAdmin
    edit do
      field :name
      field :properties, :text
    end
  end
end
```

If I have the serialize call above deactivated, I can set hashes in RailsAdmin in the following format:

```
"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"
```

However, when the serialize call is not commented out (in order for the loop in the view to work), RailsAdmin crashes when saving the Hash:

```
undefined method `map' for String
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do simply this:

```
serialize :properties
```

This should work with `each` method.
Then :properties will be recognized as hash, not string.
HStore should be optional.

:properties should be String in your schema 
(I think when you're setting up HStore plugin - you put hstore type instead of string)

Comment: Just tried, unfortunately didn't work, I got the same "undefined method `each' for String" error in the view

Comment: are you assigning hash like this? `@item.properties = {"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"}`

Comment: what Rails version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.11. The data type is hstore (PostgreSQL). If I use Rails console, I can interact with the hstore / hash using the hstore query interface.

Comment: Yep, I tried {"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2"} and other ways, too, none of them seemed to worked