# Call method in model only if user is admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have a [piece of code in a model that I need but that breaks RailsAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914543/serialize-activerecordcodershstore-crashes-railsadmin):

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :properties, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
end
```

Since I haven't found a solution to fix the problem, I'm planning on only running this line of code when the user is not admin:

In the controller, I could do so by calling:

```
unless current_user.role?("Admin") # CanCan is installed
```

How can I implement something like this in the Item model? Or is there a better way (I have a feeling there is)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at cancan + rolify you can use current_user.has_role? :admin

## Edit

Devise gives you the method `current_user`
Rolify gives you the method `has_role? :admin`
Cancan gives you methods like `can? :destroy, @project`

Note on cancan: To use can and cannot methods you need to defile the abilities class

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have cancan installed but current_user is not available in my model. Not sure if I want to install rolify since I already have a RBAC system in place.

Comment: current_user comes from devise, I assumed you had already been using devise cause you listed that method.

Comment: current_user doesn't necessarily come from devise as many who use authlogic, for instance, also manually implement this method in ApplicationController per their README.

Comment: touché Matt Dressel, I guess in my mind their could only be one "que highlander sound track" authentication library, but you are correct.